# Mobius transformation that maps interior of a circle to a half plane bijectively

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

Construct a Mobius transformation that maps the interior of the circle $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z-3|=2\}$ bijectively onto the half plane $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:Re(z)<-1 \}$.
I drew the two graphs but I don't know what to do next.
I'm having trouble in starting the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever seen the Möbius transformation that maps the interior of the unit disc $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$ bijectively onto the upper half plane $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : Re(z) > 0\}$?

Comment: Yes. But i'm not very comfortable with this disk given in the question.

Comment: The set $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-3|=2\}$ is not actually a disc, it is a circle and it is the boundary circle of the disc $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-3| < 2\}$. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Take $1$ to $\infty$ so that the circle is sent to the line $Re(z)=-1$. Then we need to send two symmetric points to symmetric point of the line. Hence we may choose to send $4$ to $-2$ and $7$ to $0$. Thus for $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, we have $c=-d$ from the first point, $4a+b=-8c-2d$ from the second point, and $7a+b=0$. From here it is all algebra.